# Reading the temperature data from BGM220-EK4314A using web bluetooth

Tags: temperature, web-bluetooth

I am new to the Web Bluetooth API and trying to read the temperature data from my BGM220-EK4314A. the explorer kit doesn't have an in built temperature sensor but there is a piece of code in it which mimics the temperature sensor and advertises temperature data between 27 and 30 degrees in increments of 1 degree every second. the code for it is already provided in the demo "Health Thermometer example" in the Simplicity Studio. and I had flashed it and checked with the nRf Connecr app. Now, I am trying to read the same temperature data using a web app (using web Bluetooth API), but unfortunately I am unable to do so. I shall paste my code below here.

```js
var deviceName = "Thermometer Example";

var gattCharacteristics;

function isWebBLEAvailable() {
  if (!navigator.bluetooth) {
    console.log("Web BLE unavailable");
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("Web BLE available");
    return true;
  }
}

function getDeviceInfo() {
  let options = {
    optionalServices: [0x1801, 0x180a, 0x1800],
    filters: [{ name: deviceName }, { services: ["health_thermometer"] }],

    //acceptAllDevices: true // Option to accept all devices
  };

  console.log("Requesting Device Info....");

  var $target = document.getElementById("target");
  navigator.bluetooth
    .requestDevice(options)
    .then((device) => {
      console.log("Name: " + device.name);
      console.log("Initiating GATT connect");
      return device.gatt.connect();
    })
    .then((server) => {
      console.log("gatt connected");
      console.log("initiating Primary service");
      return server.getPrimaryService("health_thermometer");
    })
    .then((service) => {
      console.log("Primary service resolved");
      console.log("getting the characteristic");
      return service.getCharacteristic("temperature_measurement");
    })
    .then((characteristic) => {
      console.log("characteristic resolved");
      console.log("reading value");
      characteristic.addEventListener(
        "characteristicvaluechanged",
        handleTempChanged
      );
      return characteristic.getDescriptor(
        "gatt.client_characteristic_configuration"
      );
    })
    .then((descriptor) => {
      return descriptor.readValue();
    })
    .then((value) => {
      console.log("value read!!");
      console.log(`Value is : ${value.getUint8(0)}`);
      $target.innerHTML = "Value is " + value.getUint8(0) + ".";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
}

function handleTempChanged(event) {
  let newTemp = event.target.value.getUint8(0);
  console.log("value changed");
  console.log("New Temperature is: " + newTemp);
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  if (isWebBLEAvailable()) {
    getDeviceInfo();
  }
});
```

I am unable to read out the right temperature data and also, the change in temperature every 1 second isn't displayed either. (even after adding the event listener).
Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear where it fails. Are you able to pick the device? Can you share console logs so that we see which promise fails?

Comment: Hello @François Beaufort, thanks for the response. Yes, i am able to pick up the device. I shall share the console log here
[`code`]
Web BLE available
index.html:46 Requesting Device Info....
index.html:50 Name: Thermometer Example
index.html:51 Initiating GATT connect
index.html:54 gatt connected
index.html:55 initiating Primary service
index.html:59 Primary service resolved
index.html:60 getting the characteristic
index.html:65 characteristic resolved
index.html:66 reading value
index.html:78 value read!!
index.html:85 Value is : 0

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should read the `"temperature_measurement"` characteristic value, not the `"gatt.client_characteristic_configuration"` descriptor of this characteristic.

```js
  navigator.bluetooth
    .requestDevice(options)
    .then((device) => {
      console.log("Name: " + device.name);
      console.log("Initiating GATT connect");
      return device.gatt.connect();
    })
    .then((server) => {
      console.log("gatt connected");
      console.log("initiating Primary service");
      return server.getPrimaryService("health_thermometer");
    })
    .then((service) => {
      console.log("Primary service resolved");
      console.log("getting the characteristic");
      return service.getCharacteristic("temperature_measurement");
    })
    .then((characteristic) => {
      console.log("characteristic resolved");
      console.log("reading value");
      return characteristic.readValue();
    })
    .then((value) => {
      console.log("value read!!");
      console.log(`Value is : ${value}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello @François Beaufort, I am using the bgm220-explorer kit and there is a demo program running in it and as per the code, the "temperature_measurement" characteristic does not have "read" property in it, but it has a descriptor with read property. Also, rather than using the notifications, the explorer kit program uses "indications". Is there any specific way to read the indications or can I use gattcharacteristic.startNotifications() itself?

Comment: Got it! `gattcharacteristic.startNotifications()` should work.

Comment: Note that I wasn't able to find descriptor in https://github.com/SiliconLabs/EFRConnect-android/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/siliconlabs/bledemo/HealthThermometer/Activities/HealthThermometerActivity.kt. Is this expected?

Comment: Thank you so much @François Beaufort for the help. I shall look into it. :)